# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (210) to match target batch_size (49)

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project and I'm running into the issue **"ValueError: Expected input batch_size (168) to match target batch_size (1)."** in
**loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), hidden_emotion.repeat(output.shape[1], 1).view(-1))** I've tried a lot of things and couldn't solve it, does anyone know how to fix it

My code is as follows:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


def tokenize(text):
    return [token.text for token in nlp.tokenizer(text)]


TEXT = Field(sequential=True, tokenize=tokenize, lower=True)
LABEL = Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False, dtype=torch.float)


with open("AI_daliydia.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

dialogs = []
hide_emotion = []
emotions = []
for row in data["rows"]:
    dialog = row["row"]["dialog"]
    hide_emotion_dialog = row["row"]["hide_emotion"]
    emotion_dialog = row["row"]["emotion"]

    dialogs.extend(dialog)

   
    hide_emotion.extend(hide_emotion_dialog)
    emotions.extend(emotion_dialog)


fields = [("text", TEXT), ("hide_emotion", LABEL), ("emotion", LABEL)]
examples = [torchtext.data.Example.fromlist([dialogs[i], hide_emotion[i], emotions[i]], fields) for i in
            range(len(dialogs))]
dataset = torchtext.data.Dataset(examples, fields)

train_data, val_data, test_data = dataset.split(split_ratio=[0.7, 0.2, 0.1])

BATCH_SIZE = 185
train_iterator, val_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, val_data, test_data),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text),
    sort_within_batch=False
)
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, vectors=None, unk_init=None, min_freq=1,
                 specials_first=False, vectors_cache=None, specials=['<unk>', '<pad>', '<sos>', '<eos>'])


class SentimentAnalysisModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False):
        super(SentimentAnalysisModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=num_layers, bidirectional=bidirectional,
                           batch_first=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2 if bidirectional else hidden_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, output_dim)

    def forward(self, text):
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
        output, _ = self.rnn(embedded)

        output = self.fc1(output)
        output = F.relu(output)
        output = self.fc2(output)

        return output


model = SentimentAnalysisModel(vocab_size=len(TEXT.vocab),
                               embedding_dim=100,
                               hidden_dim=256,
                               output_dim=8,
                               bidirectional=True)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())


def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for batch in iterator:
        text = batch.text
        hidden_emotion = batch.hide_emotion.view(-1, 1).long()

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(text)
        print(f"output.shape: {output.shape}")
        print(f"hidden_emotion.shape: {hidden_emotion.shape}")
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), hidden_emotion.repeat(output.shape[1], 1).view(-1))

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss.item()

    return epoch_loss / len(iterator)


def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion):
    model.eval()
    epoch_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in iterator:
            text = batch.text
            hidden_emotion = batch.hide_emotion.view(-1, 1).long()  

            output = model(text)

            loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), hidden_emotion.squeeze())  

            epoch_loss += loss.item()

    return epoch_loss / len(iterator)


N_EPOCHS = 10
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    train_loss = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion)
    val_loss = evaluate(model, val_iterator, criterion)

    print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1:02}')
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train PPL: {math.exp(train_loss):7.3f}')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {val_loss:.3f} |  Val. PPL: {math.exp(val_loss):7.3f}')

test_loss = evaluate(model, test_iterator, criterion)
print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.3f} | Test PPL: {math.exp(test_loss):7.3f}')
```

Full error log:

```
output.shape: torch.Size([30, 7, 8])
hidden_emotion.shape: torch.Size([7, 1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\桌面\Zu_bot\AI\Zu_AI(en2).py", line 136, in <module>
    train_loss = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\桌面\Zu_bot\AI\Zu_AI(en2).py", line 104, in train
    loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), hidden_emotion.repeat(output.shape[1], 1).view(-1))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (210) to match target batch_size (49).
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks, Vinny